# Can I use Tabulator js library in my java Spring + Thymeleaf project?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, thymeleaf, tabulator

I want to add Tabulator js to my java project. 
I added tabulator.min.js, tabulator.min.css to resources folder.
After that added to my html page these dependencies as recommending in readme.md.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/tabulator.min.css}">
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/tabulator.min.js}"></script>
```

Now my tables view all elements, that I have in the html page, but not correct.

In the documentation of Tabulator is example how to create header and table,

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    columns:[
        {title:"Name", field:"name", sorter:"string", width:200, editor:true},
        {title:"Age", field:"age", sorter:"number", align:"right", formatter:"progress"},
        {title:"Gender", field:"gender", sorter:"string", cellClick:function(e, cell){console.log("cell click")},},
        {title:"Height", field:"height", formatter:"star", align:"center", width:100},
        {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col", sorter:"string"},
        {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", sorter:"date", align:"center"},
        {title:"Cheese Preference", field:"cheese", sorter:"boolean", align:"center", formatter:"tickCross"},
    ],
});
```

but I want to create header in html, is it possible?

And put data in server-side part from controllers, not as

```js
var data = [
  {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", age:"12", col:"red", dob:""},
  {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982"},
  {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982"},
  {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", age:"125", col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
  {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", age:"16", col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
];
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you be a bit more specific about what you mean by "create header in html,"? 
 Tabulator is designed to create interactive JavaScript tables, it is not designed to output a simple HTML table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tabulator is designed to create interactive JavaScript tables, it is not designed to output a simple HTML table

Comment: I have the complicated html page, but I created this page on the back-end with all data).  And I was so disappointed that I can work with tabulator with my html.

Comment: Tabulator is designed to run on the front end, there is nothing to stop you putting the javascript from your server to turn your table into a Tabulator